# Problemas ao iniciar IIS Express via c#

Tags: c#, wpf, iis

Preciso iniciar o IIS Express via C# com WPF. Até consigo subir o site e navegar, porém por apenas alguns segundos. Logo o site para de responder as solicitações, e só volta responder quando fecho o aplicativo.

```
private void WinPrincipal_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  IniciarSite();
}

public void IniciarSite()
{
    string path = @"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe";
    string argumentos = @"/path:C:\Sites /port:9090 /systray:true";

   if (!File.Exists(path))
      throw new FileNotFoundException();

   var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
     FileName = path,
     Arguments = argumentos,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = true
   });
}
```

Inicialmente achei que era porque eu estava usando algumas portas não comuns como 9092, 8082. Ai comecei testar com a 9090, mas também acontece, para de responder e só volta quando fecha o aplicativo.

Também notei que quando eu compilo em "debug" o problema acontece, porém ao compilar em "release" funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema através da criação de um Console Application que faz o lançamento do IISExpress. Eu passo os argumentos para essa aplicação, ela se encarrega de iniciar o processo do IIS então fecha, retornando o código do processo criado através do código da saída(exit code)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
            Environment.Exit(-1);

        string exeIIS = args[0];
        string caminhoFisico = args[1];
        string porta = args[2];

        string argumentos = CriarArgumentosInicializacaoIISExpress(caminhoFisico, porta);
        int processoID = LancarIISExpress(argumentos, exeIIS);

        Environment.Exit(processoID);
    }

    private static int LancarIISExpress(string argumentos, string pathExeIIS)
    {
        var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = pathExeIIS,
            Arguments = argumentos,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        });

        return process.Id;
    }

    private static string CriarArgumentosInicializacaoIISExpress(string caminhoFisico, string porta)
    {
        var argumentos = new StringBuilder();
        argumentos.Append(@"/path:" + caminhoFisico);
        argumentos.Append(@" /Port:" + porta);
        return argumentos.ToString();
    }
}
```